# Making PHPCS understand square brackets as array initializer on eclipse

Tags: php, arrays, eclipse, eclipse-pdt, phpcs

I'm using Eclipse Mars.1 with the latest version of PDT and the latest PHPCS. I'm using a variant of the PEAR formatter on my PHPCS and there is one behaviour that is annoying as hell. It does not understand the identation of a square bracket as array initialization.

For example, the code below will show as valid, as not having any formatting error.

```
funcCall(
    array(
        'value',
        'value2',
        'value3',
    )
);
```

But if I do

```
funcCall(
    [
        'value',
        'value2',
        'value3',
    ]
);
```

It complains that the values should be indented together with the brackets. As if the values where part of the function call, and not on an array that is inside it.

EDIT: As requested here is the return from running PHPCS on the command line, looks like the problem is on Eclipse.

> standard... DONE (13 sniffs registered)
>   Creating file list... DONE (1 files in queue)
>   Changing into directory [MY DIRECTORY] 
>   Processing File.php [PHP => 564 tokens in 74 lines]... DONE in 76ms (0 > errors, 0 warnings)
>   Time: 574ms; Memory: 3.25Mb

EDIT 2: Just Updated to Mars.2 and the latest of the PDT tools, still the same issue.

Comment: Any chance you could run PHPCS directly on that code and see what errors are produced? I'm not sure if you are asking about a PHPCS issue or an Eclipse formatting issue.

Comment: @GregSherwood I just edited the question. Looks like it is on the eclipse side, not on PHPCS

Comment: Looks like it might be, yeah. Sorry I can't help with that.